# IQtNetwork.QHttp request credential issue

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, twisted, twisted.web

I am currently authenticating via a RESTful http api that generates a token which is then used for subsequent request.

The api server is written with python twisted and works great
the auth token generation works fine in browsers

When requesting from software written in pyqt
the first request hands over a token to the pyqt app
while subsequent request from the pyqt app fails because the remote twisted server believes it is another browser entirely.

javascript ajax does this too but is solvable by sending xhrFields: {withCredentials: true} along with the request.

How do I resolve this in PyQt?

Answer (score 1):

So i figured out that Qt isn't sending the TWISTED_SESSION cookie back with subsequent requests.
all i did was send the cookie along with subsequent requests and it worked fine.
i had to sqitch to python's request to ease things